# To check if a user has a role (admin or any other custom role) in a server, from the user's DM

Tags: discord, discord.py

When a user DM's the bot and uses a command, like let's say `-server <server id>`, the bot should check if the user is:

1. A member of the guild
2. Has administrator role(or a custom role) within that particular guild.

```
   def dm_server(self, msg):       
          
        guildid=msg.content.split(" ",1)     #splitting the `-server <servid>`
        guildid=int(guildid[1])              #storing guild id 

        guild=self.bot.get_guild(guildid)

        member=msg.author

        #<check here if member has admin or custom role within the guild>
```

I tried using `if member.guild_permissions.administrator:` but got the error `AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'guild_permissions'`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need the `Member` object if you want to use `guild_permissions`.

In the context of a DM, it will give you a `discord.User`, so you'll need to get the proper permissions by getting the member for the corresponding guild.

```py
guild = self.bot.get_guild(guildid)
member = guild.get_member(msg.author.id)
# member.guild_permissions
```

Comment: Thx for replying. It fixed the earlier error but now I'm getting a different error. 

`if member.guild_permissions.administrator:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'guild_permissions'`

Comment: That means the member you have probably either does not exist or you were unable to get it. Try `await guild.fetch_member(id)` and see if that addresses it

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked. Sorry for the late reply (I was on tour).